# O que é Edge Computing?

Tags: sistemas-distribuídos, iot

O que seria o Edge Computing? Qual a relação dele com a industria 4.0 e Cloud Computing?

Answer (score -1):

***Edge Computing* é a tradução de Computação de borda.**

A computação de borda é um paradigma de computação distribuída que aproxima a computação e o armazenamento de dados das fontes de dados.

Espera-se que isso melhore os tempos de resposta e economize largura de banda, a *Edge Computing* é uma arquitetura e não uma tecnologia específica, se na computação tradicional, os dados trafegam até um *data center* centralizado para então serem processados, na *Edge Computing* isso não acontece.